# Get Spring PathVariable case sensitively

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

Spring's Path variable when bound to variables change themselves to lowercase. Say , I have a URL Scheme `/company/{{name}}` , the name after being bound to variable

```
@PathVariable(value="name") String name
```

will itself be in lowercase. Is
it possible to extract `name` as it was passed in the request ?

Comment: *Spring's Path variable when bound to variables change themselves to lowercase*: no, they don't. I just tested it in a brand new Spring Boot 2.0.1 project.

Comment: Not talking about spring boot , talking about spring 5.0

Comment: Spring Boot is a wrapper around Spring Framework 5.

Comment: *Spring's Path variable when bound to variables change themselves to lowercase* **NO It doesn't**